# pass the argument in the shell script command

Tags: linux, shell, sh

Hi I am creating a shell script file in that I have stored the input of command in the **name** variable and that variable is passed to another command as follows

```
name=`v4l2-sysfs-path -d | grep "video" | awk 'NR==1 { split($0,a,"("); gsub(" |\t","",a[1]); print a[1] }'`
echo $name    
path=`v4l2-sysfs-path -d | awk -F' ' '/"$name"/{ printf prev_f2 };{ prev_f2 = $2 }'`
echo $path
```

when I print the **$path** it doesn't show me any output but If I tried following

```
path=`v4l2-sysfs-path -d | awk -F' ' '/video0/ { printf prev_f2 };{ prev_f2 = $2 }'`
echo $path
```

it shows me output as `pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-5:`
how can I pass the **name** parameter to **path**

Comment: Yet another __FAQ__.  `awk -vname=$name '{print name}'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
path=`v4l2-sysfs-path -d | awk -F' ' /"$name"/'{ printf prev_f2 };{ prev_f2 = $2 }'`
echo $path
```